# How to swipe change just a image instead of a whole activity

Tags: java, android

So right now I have it so I can swipe and it changes views or activitys
but how can I do it so it just changed the middle box only? With the sound clips in it

Im making this app to learn

this is the source i used
http://www.easyway2in.blogspot.ae/2014/07/android-swipe-views-example.html

and my video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qD039kXYPLM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of having the `ViewPager` the only item inside `activity_main`
you should put the header and footer you want to remain unchanged inside `activity_main`,
so that the fragments in the viewpager only contains your "middle box"